# Div/List with 100% width + padding + bottom align

Tags: html, css, list, alignment, padding

Noob question..
I can't seem to get all 3 aspects.

```
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: red;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    width: auto;
```

Currently the list won't stretch 100%+padding.
If I change the width to 100% then the padding on the right disappears.
If I change the position to 'relative' then it looks the way I want, but obviously wont align to the bottom of the page.
Help?

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` + `width: 100%` would do the trick.

Comment: A piece of HTML would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`box-sizing` property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#box-sizing), set to `border-box`:

> The specified width and height (and respective min/max properties) on this element determine the border box of the element. That is, **any padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified width and height**. The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified ‘width’ and ‘height’ properties.

```css
elem {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nxvbem5/).

Answer (score 0):

The right margin doesn't really disappear, but the width of an element is calculated as the width you specified + padding an borders. So when you set the width to 100% and the padding to 80px, then then element becomes 80px wider than the body.

You can change this behaviour by adding `box-sizing: border-box`. Bringing them together:

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: red;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    
    /* Add both lines below */
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Testa</li>    
    <li>Testb</li>    
    <li>Testc</li>    
    <li>Testd</li>    
    <li>Teste</li>    
    <li>Testf</li>    
    <li>Testg</li>
    <li>Testh</li>    
    <li>Testi</li>
    <li>Testj</li>    
    <li>Testk</li>
    <li>Testl</li>    
    <li>Testm</li>
    <li>Testn</li>    
    <li>Testo</li>
    <li>Testp</li>    
    <li>Testq</li>
    <li>Testr</li>    
    <li>Tests</li>
</ul>
```